# Cannot register stdole assembly in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqlclr

I am in the process of migrating a SQL Server 2008 to 2012 and running into challenges in creating some of the necessary assemblies for a CLR routine. The routine takes a dependency on `stdole.dll`, but I am unable to create this assembly. My code is as follows:

```
ALTER DATABASE main SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;

create assembly [stdole]
from
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\stdole.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = unsafe
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
Warning: The Microsoft .NET Framework assembly 'stdole, version=7.0.3300.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.' you are registering is not fully tested in the SQL Server hosted environment and is not supported. In the future, if you upgrade or service this assembly or the .NET Framework, your CLR integration routine may stop working. Please refer SQL Server Books Online for more details.
Msg 10332, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Assembly "stdole" was built using version v1.0.3705 of the .NET Framework. SQL Server currently uses version v4.0.30319.
```

I am currently logged in with an account that has sysadmin privileges so i have `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permissions.

Please help! I have been researching this for hours but cannot find anything that works.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error? I only see a warning.

Comment: @TomTom: that first line is a warning, but the 2 lines below it are a hard-error.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be calling Office Interop Assemblies from SQL Server! I'd recommend an alternative approach (such as a job queue table in the database, and a .NET CLI App that does the work - maybe run by task scheduler every few mins to check the queue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key info is in the two different .Net versions noted in the error:

> Assembly "stdole" was built using version v1.0.3705 of the .NET Framework. SQL Server currently uses version v4.0.30319

Microsoft SQL Server does not allow for mixed-mode CLR. Meaning, it is statically linked to a particular series. SQL Server 2005, 2008, and 2008 R2 are linked to the 2.0 series (2.0, 3.0, and 3.5) and SQL Server 2012 and 2014 are linked to the 4.0 series (4.0 and 4.5). More details can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dohollan/archive/2012/04/20/sql-server-2012-sqlclr-net-framework-version.aspx).

So, it is impossible to load that version of `stdole.dll` starting in SQL Server 2012. And unfortunately there is no other DLL in that folder that is linked to a 4.0 series framework.

**EDIT:**
Try the following as it results in a DLL that has the same `publickeytoken` (i.e. b03f5f7f11d50a3a) and loads successfully in SQL Server 2012. The idea is to extract the base code (via `ILDASM`) and then re-link that to the newer framework (via `ILASM`). I am not sure if your code will need to be recompiled.

1. Open a "Visual Studio Command Prompt" / "Developer Command Prompt" (not a regular "Command Prompt").
2. Run the following statements:
   `MKDIR C:\TEMP\stdole

   CD C:\TEMP\stdole

   XCOPY /V "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop  Assemblies\stdole.dll" .

   ILDASM stdole.dll /out:stdole.il

   ILASM /DLL /OPTIMIZE /OUTPUT=stdole-4.0.dll /RESOURCE=stdole.res stdole.il`
3. Run the following in SSMS:
   `USE [main];

   CREATE ASSEMBLY [stdole] FROM 'C:\TEMP\stdole\stdole-4.0.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;`

Notes:

- What is `stdole.dll`?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195478(office.11).aspx
- The `stdole.res` file that is mentioned as a parameter to the `ILASM` command is created by the `ILDASM` command; it is just not explicitly stated as an output file like `stdole.il` is.

Comment: @ChandlerPelhams: not a problem. It was an interesting problem to solve. I only thought of it as I had to re-sign an assembly a few months ago and did some research to find this method (but in my case I needed to do more steps for the cert). But I just took an educated guess that if disassembly was possible, then most likely re-linking would bind it to the newer framework (assuming none of the method calls had been removed). Did you have to recompile your code at all?

Comment: Nope, I was able to register all the assemblies and create the CLR procedure after using the modified `stdole.dll` file.

Comment: @ChandlerPelhams sweet :-)